# How to extend classes of tailwind in Nuxt

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am using `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` in a SSR Nuxt project, and I want to extend classes in tailwindcss like this:

Here is the key part of my `nuxt.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    ],
    css: [
        '~/assets/app.scss',
    ],
    tailwindcss: {
        cssPath: '~/assets/tailwind.css',
    }
}
```

In `app.scss`

```
#__layout{
    position: relative;
    &>main{       
        &>header>*:not(.fluid),
        &>main>*:not(.fluid),
        &>footer>*:not(.fluid){
            @extend .container;
            @extend .mx-auto;
            @extend .w-auto;
            @extend .px-2;
            @extend .sm\:px-2;
            @extend .md\:px-3;
            @extend .lg\:px-4;
        }
    }
}
```

Errors occured

> The selector ".container" was not found.
> Use "@extend .container !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.

[image: Use "@extend .container !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.]

So, I added  `!optional` for those classes:

```
            @extend .container  !optional;
            @extend .mx-auto  !optional;
            @extend .w-auto  !optional;
            @extend .px-2  !optional;
            @extend .sm\:px-2  !optional;
            @extend .md\:px-3  !optional;
            @extend .lg\:px-4  !optional;
```

node errors gone but styles are not what I expected.

How can I solve this? To extend class in tailwind correctly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is your tailwind css file located in `'~/assets/tailwind.css'` ?

Comment: @KareemDabbeet Yes, I have try to add `@import 'tailwindcss/components';@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';` in `app.scss`, but errors stills